# How to use different icons in QListWidget items

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` that is populated by different items.
Every item is decorated by icon.

Is it possible to change icon width for specific items?

Comment: Does `item->setIcon(ic);` with he desired icon work ?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I need to have ability to change icon size for specific items.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use QListView along with your custom model (inherited from QAbstractListModel), where in data() method of the model class you return corresponding icon (can be of arbitrary size) for Qt::Decoration role.

Comment: It didn't help me. I know that I can return different icons of various sizes. But QListView (and QListWidget) SCALES icons to fixed size.